# How to get count of columns on temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

shows columns of all tables except temp tables. How can I get temp tables columns, to then aggregate by table name and count them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
X INT,
Y INT
)

SELECT *
FROM tempdb.sys.columns
WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..#T')
```