# Count of Columns in temp table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to count number of columns in a temp (#temptable) table in sql server ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486253/how-to-get-count-of-columns-on-temp-table

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tempdb.sys.columns
WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..#mytemptable')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Query to get column counts for specified table**

```
SELECT Count(*) as cnt into #TempTable FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

**Query to get column names for specified table**

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME into #TempTable FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

**Query to get column count for #TempTable**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Cnt FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..#TempTable')

DROP table #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query :

```
Declare @TableName NVarChar(150)
Declare @ColumnName NVarChar(150)
Set @TableName = ''
Set @ColumnName = ''

SELECT 
    t.name AS table_name,
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
    c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns As C ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 
Where 
    ( T.name Like '%' + @TableName + '%' )
    And
    ( C.name Like '%' + @ColumnName + '%' ) 


SELECT 
    COUNT(C.Name) Count_Of_Columns,
    COUNT(Distinct T.Name) Count_Of_Tables
FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns As C ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 
Where 
    ( T.name Like '%' + @TableName + '%' )
    And
    ( C.name Like '%' + @ColumnName + '%' )
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temptable
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` will return count of number of rows

Comment: sorry. I'm misunderstanding